# Time and attendance analysis

Tags: r, excel, analytics

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I am trying to analyze the clock-in and clock-out of employees but the system shows duplicates of an employee clocking in and out during the day so we want to remove those duplicates so that it shows the first clock-in and the last clock-out of the employees. After removing the duplicates we need to count the number of employees that clock-in at specific time intervals, like before 8:00, after 8:00, between 8:00 and 8:30 etc. This data was recorded over a period of one month. There are also blank time stamps that I want to remove from the data. Any suggestions?

I tried using the "countifs" function on Excel but that was a long and tedious process since there are over a 100,000 time stamps.
[This is the expected output for clock-out time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d70qL.png)

Comment: Images are not a good way for posting data (or code). See [this Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/8245406) and a [relevant xkcd](https://xkcd.com/2116/). Can you post sample data in `dput` format? Please edit the question with the code you tried and with the output of `dput(df)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df, 20))`. (Note: `df` is the name of your dataset.)

Comment: Also, in the image, there are no duplicates *per day*. Is this right?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Why the `r` tag if you are trying to solve this in Excel? Anyways, this sounds like you may benefit from a Pivot Table to get the desired output

Comment: Hi @RuiBarradas. To be honest, I don't have experience dealing with large data and even R and Excel. I don't know how to do complex functions. You can find the data set on this link: https://transnetsocltd-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/likhona_matinjwa_transnet_net/Ee4wAxMId0FJqDULfbxrZc8BgqstEQv-BHsywEleVze20g?e=z2Jwm1. I just want guidance on how to clean and sort the data

Comment: Hi @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns. My apologize for that. I just wanted any solutions I can get, either Excel or R.

Comment: Can you post an example of expected output? Also, please, notice that your `Start` column values are being recognized as text, so you can't make any calculation with it.

Comment: I have uploaded the image with the expected output @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way of doing what the question asks for.

The first part of the code reads in the data file. Disregard it if already done.

```
path <- "~/StackOverflow/TNPA_Clocks"
flname <- list.files(path, pattern = "\\.xlsx", full.names = TRUE)
basename(flname)
# [1] "Copy of TNPA Clocks - September 2022 (002).xlsx"
df1 <- readxl::read_excel(flname)
```

---

Now the processing. Since only the times of day are relevant, I consider all records to be in the same day, then `cut` the date and times vector by the points 16:00, 16:30, 17:00. Finally, table the results and coerce to data.frame.

```
d <- Sys.Date()
datetime <- with(df1, paste(d, Start))
datetime <- as.POSIXct(datetime, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
#
breaks <- c("00:00:00", "16:00:00", "16:30:00", "17:00:00", "23:59:59")
breaks <- as.POSIXct(paste(d, breaks))
labels <- c("Before 16:00", "16:00-16:30", "16:31-17:00", "17:00 onward")
#
End_Category <- cut(datetime, breaks = breaks, labels = labels)
as.data.frame(table(End_Category))
#  End_Category  Freq
#1 Before 16:00 89800
#2  16:00-16:30 10867
#3  16:31-17:00  3827
#4 17:00 onward 26436
```